# Alert pop up with buttons that give actions

Tags: popup, action, alert

Alert pop up with buttons that give actions. I need help with having a button that allows me to share to facebook and twitter!, i already have buttons that do this but i want to incorporate it into the alert interface tips?

Comment: Can you tell your programming platform? ASP.NET, javascript, WinForms etc